# Open and edit code file from remote server in my preferred editor?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, sftp, winscp

I am having a lot of trouble solving a SFTP problem...

I would like to be able to open and edit text files in my preferred editor such that I can execute a command on my remote server and it will open the file in Visual Studio Code.  Once that file is opened in VS code, I would like to be able to edit it and, when I save, it will save the changes to the same location on the server.

I know something like this is possible because I have used WinSCP where I can double click a text file from the server through the UI and it will open it in whichever editor I choose. When I save changes, it will update those changes on the server. I really want to know what WinSCP is doing behind the scenes when I do that.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP is running on your local machine, so it can open a local editor. So, it's not comparable.

You cannot execute local a application from a remote server.

Comment: But it is connected to both my local machine and remote server and it can grab files from the server and (i think?) place them in a tmp location locally such that when I make a change and save it, it will push that edited file to the server and overwrite.  Hoping that I can use the terminal in VScode to navigate to a code file, and then open that file in the editor window (also in VScode) very quickly and easily.

Comment: *"it is connected"* - what is the *"it"*?

Comment: WinSCP?  From what I understand, I am SSH'd into my remote server